# run 2 or more subprocess call separately

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two different executable (`run1` and `run2`). I want to run them simultaneously. They share one readonly input file, but otherwise, they are different process. 
Is it possible to call the `call`'s  simultaneously?
Currently, as I have coded, `cmd2`'s call wait for `cmd1`'s call to complete.

```
with open(dosout, "w") as dout, open(jijout, "w") as jout:
    cmd1 = ["mpirun", "-np", "8", "~/WORK/run1", dosinp]
    cmd2 = ["mpirun", "-np", "8", "~/WORK/run2", jijinp]
    call(cmd1, stdout=dout)
    call(cmd2, stdout=jout)
dout.close()
jout.close()
```

Is it possible with `call`?  or `Popen` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24313858/2005559) answer is the only (or better) way out?

Comment: call waits for the process to return, Popen does not so yes you can use Popen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call

Comment: related: [Python threading multiple bash subprocesses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14533458/4279)

Comment: unlrelated: `subprocess` does **not** use the shell unless you  ask; do you need to call `os.path.expanduser("~/WORK/run2")` here?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `Popen` as described in the answer you linked (and quite a few other places as well, because `Popen` is a slightly lower-level interface which is often needed).

Answer (score 0):

To run two subprocesses concurrently:

```
from subprocess import Popen

# start processes
with open(dosout, "wb", 0) as dout, open(jijout, "wb", 0) as jout:
    processes = [Popen(["mpirun", "-np", "8", "...WORK/run1", cmd], stdout=file)
                 for cmd, file in [(dosinp, dout), (jijinp, jout)]]

# wait for them to finish
statuses = [p.wait() for p in processes]
```

Note: the file are closed on exit from the `with`-statement, don't call `.close()` manually.